# Problem when run script in boot

Tags: boot, scripts, 16.04

I created the following *script*:

```
#!/bin/bash

su administrador -c "/home/administrador/scripts/startup_tomcat_hsqldb.sh"
```

I added in `/etc/init.d` . When I run the *command*:

```
sudo update-rc.d start-tomcat-auto.sh defaults
```

and I got the following *message*:

```
insserv: warning: script 'K01start-tomcat-auto.sh' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: warning: script 'start-tomcat-auto.sh' missing LSB tags and overrides
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Scripts should include more info but its just a warning it should work right. So something else is the problem. Why do you need the 'su' command?

Answer (score 0):

I think init scripts need stuff like this at the begining :

```
# Provides: chillispot et freeradius dans le chroot 
# Required-Start:    $local_fs $network
# Required-Stop:     $local_fs $remote_fs
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Short-Description: Wireless & LAN Access Point Controller
# Description:       ChilliSpot is an open source captive portal
#                    or wireless LAN access point controller.
### END INIT INFO
```

edit : see here https://wiki.debian.org/LSBInitScripts